# Desk fan not starting. No hums and blades don't spin

Tags: fans, electric-motor, capacitor

I have a desk fan I've been using for almost two years but for whatever reason, it stopped working whenever I try to turn it on. The fan has three speed control buttons and none of them works. I also tried nudging the blades first to give the motor a kick-start but it still doesn't spin. I also don't hear any hum from the motor whenever I turn it on.

What could be the problem here? Is it the capacitor or is there some kind of fuse I've blown in the fan?

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because small appliance repair is off topic here. Please see https://diy.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic.

Answer (score 2):

It is time to replace it. More than like your berings froze up probably causing the motor winding to fail. There normally is a thermal link that is buried in the winding that did what it should have and opened preventing a fire. Some fans also have a fuse in the line corde, many times molded in the plug designed not to be replaced. Sorry about your loss but you will like the new one even better. If you have the tools you can check to see if the circuit is open, if not you could clean and lubricate the bearings.

Comment: So it's probably not the capacitor? Could I easily troubleshoot if it's really the capacitor or the fuse which went kaput? However, I don't think it's the bearing since I could easily rotate the shaft by hand unlike the past fan I had had which is difficult to do the same. I also tried opening the casing and the dust build-up isn't really that much since I regularly clean it.

Comment: You did check that the outlet has power?  Could also be a connection at the switch has failed.

Comment: "Could I easily troubleshoot" Probably not, @KoshoE. Modern appliances such as this are designed to be thrown away, not repaired. Just to give you an idea, use your favorite search engine for `<brand> <model number> replacement parts` and see what comes up. Sure, you could use any generic capacitor if that's what's gone bad, but I'm 99.999% certain you won't find a replacement blade assembly, motor, blade protection housing, or other repair parts. Also, it could be the buttons or a button assembly connection that quit working.